# How to properly logon to mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

This is a beginner mySQL question.

I was looking at some article's and youtubes, about mySQL and C# login forms. When I noted that each solution and article started with a form that performs login with "root" account, and then checked against a user-password table inside the database.

For example the code below does that:

```
public partial class Login_Form_2 : Form
{
    public Login_Form_2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Root level login ??
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(
    "datasource=localhost;port=3310;Initial Catalog='test';username=root;password="
    );

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    private void BTN_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" + textBox_username.Text + "' AND `password` = '" + textBox_password.Text + "'", connection);
        adapter.Fill(table);

        if(table.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            panel1.Height = 0;
            label_Message.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label_Message.Text = "Username Or Password Are Invalid";
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Height = 0;
            label_Message.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            label_Message.Text = "Login Successfully";
            timer1.Start();
        }
        table.Clear();
    }
}
```

I think root passwords should not be in client side code.

And i also wonder if such user-password tables are permission-assignable. 
 So users user X is allowed to add certain field of table Z but not to table Y.

So is this really the way a login should look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a client sided  application I suggest you retrieve information through API calls.

If not check out my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468042/c-sharp-connect-to-mysql-through-user-control/43469383#43469383) for some insight as to how I directly connect to the database. Make sure you use `Parameters` to prevent SQL-Injection.

Comment: I'm concerned in the above example code i gave about its connection string. Its a database with 'internal' user table, but it logs using root account of the mySQL server, i see that happen in a lot of examples, but i want to logon not with root, but only with people in a specific database-table

Comment: You never want to build a client-sided application that connects directly to the database. If you want to have access to a database you should always split the client side with the server side. You could possibly build a separate application on your server to handle the calls, or build a website and run data through API's.