# Using a checkbox to reference database synonyms? C#

Tags: c#, database, checkbox, datasource

sorry if this is an easy fix im very new to programming and having a bit of trouble but will try to explain best i can.
Currently i have a winforms project where i select any directory within my first text box and all sub directories and files show in a list box. After which i search for a term in my 2nd text box, and the list box returns any files containing that term. Now i have connected a data source that has two rows, word and synonym. What i want to do is have a checkbox that says "include synonyms" and when clicked, searching for a term will also return any files containing the corresponding synonyms within the connected data source. Im not quite sure how to do this and am really just stabbing in the dark, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need some more information to work with. A checkbox returns true or false, if you have a search term it should be incorporated with your SQL-statement. The text box returns a string. You might want to use the LIKE Operator: [moreover](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

For the connection, I will refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468042/c-sharp-connect-to-mysql-through-user-control/43469383#43469383) post of mine. Make sure you use parameters to avoid SQL-injection.

Also, add some of your code so we can see what is actually going wrong. Hope this helps.