# How to redraw everything after Refresh() on windows form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 9 rectangles and I need to draw a text inside them, I have two buttons which they are choosing the text that I need to draw into.
when I click on the button then click on the rectangle it will take the location of mouse and then check in which rectangle I need to draw into.
when I need to draw in another rectangle because of Refresh() it drew the new one and clear the past draw.
How can I save it?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Rectangle> rects = new List<Rectangle>();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        string str;
        Point start;
        int x = 0;
        Point[] points=new Point[100];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    rects.Add( new Rectangle(130 + (j * 130), 130 + (i * 130), 130, 130));

                }
            }
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Rectangle rect in rects)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);

           
                getRectangle(rectangle);
                if (rectangle.Width != 0 && rectangle.Height != 0)
                {
                    using (SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen))
                    {
                        using (FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"))
                        {
                            using (Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 20))
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(str, font, solidBrush, rectangle.X + 55, rectangle.Y + 55);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        private void Cross_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            str = "X";

        }

        private void Circle_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            str = "O";
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            start = e.Location;
            points[x] = start;
            x++;
            Invalidate();
        }

        public void getRectangle(Rectangle rectan)
        {
            rectangle.Width = 0;
            rectangle.Height = 0;
            if (str == "X")
            {
                foreach(Rectangle rect in rects)
                        if (rect.Contains(start))
                        {
                            rectangle.X = rect.X;
                            rectangle.Y = rect.Y;
                            rectangle.Width = rect.Width;
                            rectangle.Height = rect.Height;
                          
                        }
            }
            else if (str == "O")
            {
                
                    foreach (Rectangle rect in rects)
                        if (rect.Contains(start))
                        {
                            rectangle.X = rect.X;
                            rectangle.Y = rect.Y;
                            rectangle.Width = rect.Width;
                            rectangle.Height = rect.Height;

                        }
                
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Build a class object that can store a Rectangle and its related Text. Use a `List<class>` instead of simply a `List<Rectangle>`. You can then associate a Text to draw with the Rectangle shape that contains it. You can also further expand your object descriptor (the class object), to include other details: e.g., the border and fill Color of the Rectangle shape, the Color of Text, the size of the Pen etc. Really easy to expand based on new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but it seems as though you need to create a database to save your object into. Look into [SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) and [UML](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_basic_notations.htm) moddeling. Once you are familiar with those consider taking a look at this older post of mine on how to extract data from a database [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468042/c-sharp-connect-to-mysql-through-user-control/43469383#43469383).

(Sidenote: There are many different ways to generate database entities in code, one of which is [Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx), once you get comfortable with SQL you should consider looking into these options)

If you want to temporarily save data (this means during the runtime of your application), consider making `objects` and fill a `List<T>` with those objects. Then you can create a loop and retreive those objects. Like so:

```
//create new class
public class Drawing
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
    public Drawing(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

//Initiate new object
public List<Drawing> drawings = new List<Drawing>();

//Add this to your loop
drawings.Items.Add(new Drawing() { X= YourX, Y= YourY });

//And foreach loop through your drawings to draw them.
foreach(Drawing drawing in drawings)
{
   //Draw your item here.
}
```